# $_POST not working

Tags: php, mysql

I cannot get my $_POST to work for some reason..Here is the code:

****Javascript that gets called from href onClick event:****

```
function feedVote(postId, vote) {
    if(vote == "1") {
        document.getElementById('voteUpSpan' + postId).innerHTML = "Thank you for voting!";
        document.getElementById('voteDownSpan' + postId).innerHTML = "";
        var i = new Image();
        var d = new Date();
        i.src = "voteUp.php?time=" + d.getTime() + "&postId=" + postId;
    }
}
```

So it spoofs a image and runs my voteUp.php page passing the parameters without changing the current page.

```
<?php
    $id = $_POST['postId'];
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password");
    if (!$con)
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("database", $con);

    $update = mysql_query("UPDATE posts SET upvote = upvote + 1 WHERE id = '$id'");

    mysql_close($con);
    echo "$id";
?>
```

The echo "$id"; returns nothing so its obviously not even putting a variable in $id which is why my sql statement is not being run but why...

When I run the code in Google Crome, I use the network tracking feature under Inspect source code and this is the url it fires off when it runs my spoof image.

**test.com/voteUp.php?time=1327644851907&postId=35**

**I editted some of the information out like my database name and username/password and website url.

Comment: You are using GET, not POST!! $id = intval($_GET['postId']);

Comment: Always don't trust any user inputs, use `intval` and similar functions.

Answer (score 3):

Those parameters are known as *GET* params, not POST.

Use the `$_GET` super global (use it in the same way as `$_POST`) to access them.

Comment: durrrrrrrrrrp Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

If you want post, do some jquery ajax post, like this:

Instead of:

```
var i = new Image();
var d = new Date();
i.src = "voteUp.php?time=" + d.getTime() + "&postId=" + postId;
```

change it with this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "voteUp.php",
    cache: false,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {time: d.getTime(), postId: postId},
    success: function(data){}
});
```

Note: you need jquery on that webpage!

Comment: I have jquery on the page already but that code did not work. It didn't increment my vote in the database.

Comment: print the $_POST and the query. you will find that way the error

Answer (score 0):

Variables that appear in the query string of the URL (i.e. after the `?` character) are accessed using the `$_GET` array rather than `$_POST`.